# Showing a solution is unique

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $F:\;[a,b]\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ continuous where $0\in [a,b]$ and for some $K>0$: 
>   $$||F(t,x)-F(t,y)||\leq K||x-y||$$ for all $x,y$ and all $t\in [a,b]$.
>
> I would like to show that there is unique continuous
>   $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ solving: $$f(t)=\int_{0}^t F(s,f(s))\; ds$$

**Idea:**

I know a weaker statement: if we have the conditions above but instead, for $B_R$ a closed ball of radius $R$ centered at $0:$

$$\mathbf{1.} \;F:\;[a,b]\times B_R\to\mathbb{R}^n\quad \mathbf{2.} \;\sup ||F||\leq R(b-a)^{-1}$$

If a continuous $f:[a,b]\to B_R$ solves the equation, it is unique.

Now I realise I cannot just "let $R\to\infty$", but is it possible to use the fact above to prove the statement?

Comment: Look up the Gronwall lemma, this is a special case of it.

Comment: I think you have mistyped your condition 2, as it stands it makes the result you have pretty weak. Aside from that this is a step in the [Picard Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem).

Comment: @s.harp Thank you both for the references. Unless there is a mistake in the book condition 2 is as it should be... It seems like an unlikely typo though. So after reading about the lemma and the theorem, it seems that Picard-L (or the fact above) provides a unique local solution, and then I can somehow use the Gronwall lemma to argue that the global solution (the extension of the local one) is unique?

Comment: See this answer to a similar question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587806/picards-existence-theorem-successive-approximations-and-the-global-solution/1590414#1590414

Comment: If you are worrying about necessity to increase $R$ to prove your statement for all point in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then don't worry. You can translate any point of interest to the origin and it won't change properties of your functions. But now you'll be able to take small balls around origin to satisfy requirements of your 'weaker statement'.

Answer (score 1):

Proof of Uniqueness:

Assume that $f,g: [a,b]\to \mathbb R^n$ satisfy the integral equation:
$$
f(t)=\int_0^tF\big(s,f(s)\big)\,ds, \quad
g(t)=\int_0^tF\big(s,g(s)\big)\,ds.
$$
Clearly, $f(0)=g(0)=0$, and
$$
f(t)-g(t)=\int_0^t \Big(F\big(s,f(s)\big)-F\big(s,g(s)\big)\Big)\,ds, \quad t\in[a,b].
$$
We use the fact that $\Big\|\int_c^d G(t)\,dt\,\Big\|\le \int_c^d\|G(t)\|\,dt,$
and obtain that, for $t\ge 0$:
$$
\|f(t)-g(t)\|\le\int_0^t \Big\|F\big(s,f(s)\big)-F\big(s,g(s)\big)\Big\|\,ds\le \int_0^t K\|f(s)-g(s)\|\,ds \quad t\ge 0.\tag{1}
$$
Set $\varphi(t)=\int_0^t \|\,f(s)-g(s)\|\,ds$. Then $\varphi'(t)=\|\,f(t)-g(t)\|$,
and hence $\varphi$ satisfies the inequality:
$$
\varphi'(t)\le K\varphi(t), \quad t\ge 0.
$$
Note that $\varphi(0)=0$. Multiply the above by $\mathrm{e}^{-Kt}$ and obtain
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-Kt}\big(\varphi'(t)- K\varphi(t)\big)\le 0, \quad t\ge 0,
$$
or
$$
\big(\mathrm{e}^{-Kt}\varphi(t)\big)'\le 0, \quad t\ge 0,
$$
and integrating the continuous function above in $[0,t]$ we obtain
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-Kt}\varphi(t)-\varphi(0)=\int_0^t\big(\mathrm{e}^{-Ks}\varphi(s)\big)'\,ds\le 0, \quad t\ge 0.
$$
But $\varphi(0)=0$, and thus
$$
0=\varphi(t)=\int_0^t \|\,f(s)-g(s)\|\,ds, \quad t\ge 0,
$$
and differentiating
$$
0=\varphi'(t)= \|\,f(t)-g(t)\|, \quad t\ge 0.
$$
The case $t\le 0$, is treated similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your integral equation is equivalent to the differential equation

$$\frac {{\rm d} f} {{\rm d} t} = F(t, f(t))$$

with the initial condition $f(0) = 0$: if $f$ solves the differential equation, then integrate to get

$$\int \limits _0 ^t F(s, f(s)) {\rm d} s = \int \limits _0 ^t \frac {{\rm d} f} {{\rm d} t} (s) {\rm d} s = f(t) - f(0) = f(t) ;$$

conversely, if $f$ solves the integral equation, then it is derivable (with continuous derivative, because $F$ is continuous), so you may derive the integral equation to get the differential one written above. Also, $f(0) = \int \limits _0 ^0 F(s, f(s)) {\rm d} s = 0$.

It is now enough to use the [Picard-Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) to obtain what you want, *many* proofs of which are easy to find with a simple web search.